# Google Maps marker custom Info getting data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, return

I'm try to get data from Firebase and load them into my marker custom view, but whenever I set the data to my textviews and imageview it doesnt show up as I belive the issue is that my code return the view before the data is loaded, so how I can go around this issue please?

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View view = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.markerinfo, null);
    final TextView nameValue =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView titleValue =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef2 = database.getReference().child(marker.getSnippet().substring(1));
    myRef2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String  title = snapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String  image = snapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);

            Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            titleValue.setText(title);
            nameValue.setText(name);

            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(image)
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, databaseError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also provide us the value that is returned by `marker.getSnippet().substring(1)`.

Comment: The data is being read from Firebase and Im getting the name, title and image but Im unable to assign these values to the respected textView and ImageView.

Comment: So if you try to log the `title` inside the `onDataChange()` is it printed out correctly?

Comment: yes, I think what happens is that the view get returned before the data is set into the TextView, not sure how to hold the return until the data is set.

Comment: You need that value outside the callback?